# Do characters share weapons?

Tags: mass-effect-3

Do you have one set of weapons for everyone or does each character have their own set? If it's the former, does selecting a weapon stop other characters from using it?

Does this also apply to weapon mods?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Weapons and also weapon mods are available for everyone once you find them. So once you find a certain weapon, Shepard and everyone in the squad can use them at the same time.

You can use different mods on a weapon for each squad mate, but every mod is available for everyone once you find it or buy it.